# How to debug a typescript in an npm package using vscode

Tags: typescript, npm, vscode-debugger

I have an `npm` package that contains the `typescript` sources and generated code. But VSCODE is unable to attach the sources. The `package.json` contains the following

```
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
     "./dist", "./src"
  ],
  "exports": {
  "import": "./dist/index.js",
  "require": "./dist/index.js"
  },
```

But, VSCode is unable to connect the typescript code into with generated java script when it was present in a npm package.

Is it possible step through `typescript`  code stored inside an `npm` package?

vscode [image]